# Carousel de bootstrap no se ajusta al contenedor

Tags: css, bootstrap

Estoy haciendo mi portfolio en codepen.Creé un carousel para mostrar fotos pero el problema es que este no se ajusta al ancho de su contenedor cuando cambio el tamaño de la ventana del navegador y sale por los costados.

```js
$('nav li').on('click', function(e){
   $('nav li').removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass('active')});
```

```css
.navbar-header{
  
  
  padding-left:15px;
  padding-right:15px;
  
}

 .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
 .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, 
 .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
      color: white;
      background:  #BDAEC6;
 }


.navbar, .navbar-inverse {
  box-shadow:10px 10px 10px #888888;
  color:white;
  background:#2E0854;
  border-width:0px;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand {
   color:white;
}




 .navbar-inverse > li > a {
    color:white;
    
}





#img1{
  width:60%;
  height:60%;
  position:relative;
  right:60px;
  
}

#p1{
  
  font-family:Bad Script;
  position:relative;
  left:40px;
 
  
}

 
.title{
  
  font-family:Lobster;
  font-size:40px;
  text-align:center;

}

.img-thumbnail {
  
    box-shadow:10px 10px 5px #888888;
    width: 458px; 
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
  
}

footer{
  background-color:#2E0854;
  margin:0px;
  padding:30px;
  height:2%;
  width:100%;
  float:bottom;
  text-align:center;
  
  
}

.btn-round{
  
  color:white;
  border-width:4px;
  margin:5px 5px 0px 6px;
  padding:5px;
  background-color:#2E0854;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:white;
  border-radius:50%;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  text-align:center;
}

.fixedbutton {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 0px; 
}

span{
  
  font-weight:bold;
  
}

#section2{
  border-radius:1%;
  padding-top:20px;
  background:#f9f9f9;
  width:80%;
  margin:20px auto;
}

form {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.form-group {
  padding: .5em 0 .5em;
  
}

.form-control {
  border-top: 0 !important;
  border-right: 0 !important;
  border-left: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  background-color: inherit !important;
}


.container-fluid{
  
  padding:0;
  
}

.jumbotron{
  margin:auto;
  margin-top:10px;
  width:80%;
  
}

.text-white{

  color:#BDAEC6;;
  font-size:20px;
  font-family:Bad Script; 
  
}

#title2{
  
  font-family:Lobster;
  font-size:40px;
  margin-bottom:15px;
  color:#6b6b6b;
  
}


#title3{
  
  font-size:40px;
  color:#6b6b6b;
  
}


.section1{
 
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
  background:#f9f9f9;
  margin-top:0px;
  

}

h4{
  
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  left:60px;
  top:40px;
  
}



#img-profile{
  
  border-radius:50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding:3% 0;
  
}

#desc{
  
  margin-top:80px;
  margin-left:30px;
  font-family:Poiret One;
  font-size:25px;
}



#career{
  
  font-family:Orbitron;
  
  
}


.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    
}


.carousel-caption{
 
 padding-top:0px; 
 bottom:-25px;
 color:black;
 background:white;
 opacity: 0.5;
  
}

#myCarousel{
  
  max-width:580px;
  margin:auto;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bad+Script|Lobster|Orbitron|Poiret+One" rel="stylesheet">


<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  
  <div class="container-fluid">
 
    <div class="navbar-header">
      
      <a class="navbar-brand" id="titles" href="index.html">MyWebSite</a>
      <button id="collapseBtn"type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNav">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    
    </div>
    
    
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNav">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#portfolio">Home <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>       
      </li>
      <li id="portfolio">
        <a href="#title2">Portfolio <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#title3">Contact <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a></li> 
      
    </ul>
 </div> 
  </div>
  </nav>
  
  
  
<div class="container-fluid">  
 
<div class="section1">
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8"> 
   <p id="desc">&lt;&gt;Informatics Engineering student at National University of la Matanza, interested in Web development.&lt;/&gt;</p>
      
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
    
     <img id="img-profile" src="http://blog.ramboll.com/fehmarnbelt/wp-content/themes/ramboll2/images/profile-img.jpg"alt="profile-photo"class="img-responsive"/>
    </div>
  
    </div>
  
    <div class="row text-center">
    <p id="career"> Informatics Engineering<p>
    </div>
  
  
</div>
  
  
<div id="section2" class="text-center">
<div class="row"> 
<div class="col-xs-12">      
  
  
<h2 id="title2" class="title">Projects</h2>

 
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/d31fbeb113.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Tribute page: Alexander Fleming</h3>
          <p>#HTML #CSS<br></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/cd5b0bae62.png" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Random quote generator</h3>
          <p>#HTML #CSS #BOOTSTRAP #JAVASCRIPT #AJAX #FORISMATIC'S API<br></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/483f82648f.png" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Wikipedia search page</h3>
          <p>#HTML #CSS #BOOTSTRAP #JAVASCRIPT #AJAX #WIKIPEDIA'S API<br></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/483f8c776e.png" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Twitch page</h3>
          <p>#HTML #CSS #BOOTSTRAP #JAVASCRIPT #AJAX #TWITCH'S API<br></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/4870f4ff6d.png" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Weather page</h3>
          <p>#HTML #CSS #BOOTSTRAP #JAVASCRIPT #AJAX #OPEN WEATHER'S API<br></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://s11.postimg.org/71f8jld1f/Sin_t_tulo.png" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Calculator</h3>
          <p>#HTML #CSS #BOOTSTRAP #JAVASCRIPT<br></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      
      

    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>  
  

</div>
</div>
</div>
  
<div class="jumbotron">
  
<p id="title3" class="title">Contact me</p>    
    
 <form action="mailto:juanolivadese@hotmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="contact-name" class="sr-only">Name</label>
              <input id="contact-name" type="text" class="form-control no-border" placeholder="Name">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="contact-email" class="sr-only">Email Address</label>
              <input id="contact-email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="contact-phone-number" class="sr-only">Phone Number</label>
              <input id="contact-phone-number" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number">
            </div>

     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-7 col-lg-7 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="contact-message" class="sr-only">Message</label>
              <textarea id="contact-message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
  
        </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
   
     </div>  
  </div>             
</div>
  
  
  <footer>
      
      <div class="row text-white" >
      ABOUT THIS PAGE<br>
        
      Created by me.<br><br>
        
      </div>
      <div class="row text-white">
      
      <p class="text-white">SOCIAL MEDIA</p>
      
      <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target='_blank' class="btn btn-lg btn-round"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true" ></i></a>
      
       <a href="http://codepen.io/Juan1417/" target='_blank' class="btn btn-lg btn-round"><i class="fa fa-codepen" aria-hidden="true" ></i></a> 
            
      <a href="http://www.twitter.com" target='_blank' class="btn btn-lg btn-round"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true" ></i></a>
      
 </div>  

<a href="#titles"class="btn btn-lg btn-round fixedbutton"><i class="fa fa-level-up" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
      </a>

</footer>
  
    
  
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Cómo se puede ver el codepen en grande para redimensionarlo? La verdad que no estoy muy acostumbrado al codepen.

Comment: Podes cambiar el tamaño de la ventana del navegador, o podes poner el mouse justo encima de donde empieza la pagina y te deja redimensionarlo.

Comment: https://i.imgsafe.org/b752e2fa11.png

Comment: Me refería para redimensionarlo de modo horizontal. Creo que sería mucho mejor si pudieras copiar el código aquí. Lo puedes introducir en tu pregunta usando Cntrl+M y se puede ver en pantalla completa sin ningún problema.

Comment: Solo el html?? el css y js tambien lo pongo?

Comment: Sí, pon todo tienes una casilla específica para cada uno. De esta manera estará en la pregunta todo junto y lo podremos ver de una forma más clara (sin tener que ir a enlaces externos, que alguna vez pueden expirar).

Comment: Usa la opción de Cntrl+M dentro de tu pregunta. Te aparecerá una nueva pantalla. Pon tu código en las casillas correspondientes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El carrusel no se ajusta al ancho del contenedor **porque así lo estás indicando**.

Esta es tu clase `MyCarousel`:

```
#myCarousel{

  max-width:580px;
  margin:auto;

}
```

¿Ves ese atributo `max-width`? Con eso le estás dando a tu carrusel un tamaño máximo de 580 px, si tu `viewport` es más pequeño, verás que se ajusta, pero si es más grande solo llega a 580 px.

Además, las imágenes de tu carrusel tienen un alto y ancho fijo, **¡no pueden ajustarse!**.

En resumen, tu carrusel se comporta como se espera. ¿No quieres ese comportamiento? **¡Cámbialo!**.

<sup>TIP: Lo más fácil es borrarlo</sup>

### Plus

No es recomendable que tengas más de un `container` en tu página, y se desaconseja usar contenedores anidados, [mira](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container).

### Bonus

Mi CodePen: http://codepen.io/jstoledano/pen/oYeQPy

Comment: Hola!!. Borre todo el css de myCarousel y saque el alto y el ancho fijo de las imagenes. Pero se sigue saliendo...:( http://codepen.io/Juan1417/pen/woqQRw

Comment: No, ya se ve bien.

Comment: Si agrando bien la pantalla el carousel se sale...:(

Comment: Si estás empezando, te recomiendo que no copies ejemplos que tal vez no entiendas todavía. Agrega elementos uno a uno y no borres lo que si funciona. Y no uses containers anidados.

Comment: Era el container gracias!!!